# unused expression when incrementing a pointer

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a problem, here's the function:

```
t_coord     cut_input(char **input){
t_coord     coords;

coords.x = ft_atoi(*input);
while (ft_isspace(**input))
    *input++;
while (!ft_isspace(**input))
    *input++;
coords.y = ft_atoi(*input);
while (ft_isspace(**input))
    *input++;
while (!ft_isspace(**input))
    *input++;
return (coords);}
```

and when I compile it says "error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
                *input++;"
I dont understand I need to increment this pointer because I call this function multiples times like that

```
t_coord var1 = cut_input(&input);
t_coord var2 = cut_input(&input);
t_coord var3 = cut_input(&input);
t_coord var4 = cut_input(&input);
```

so i'm actually using the result so is there anyway I can remove this warning ?
I even tried to put a (void)input at the end of the function, didn't work, thank you for your help

Comment: your issue is the `*`: `*ptr++` should be `ptr++` because you are not using the value `ptr` (before or after increment) points to, you just care about the increment *side-effect*.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

`*input++` is equivalent to `*(input++)`, not `(*input)++` as you might expect, because postincrement has higher priority than dereference. Since you don't use deferenced value you see unused result error.

- If you mean increment pointer (get element `input` points to if `input` points to an array member for example and make `input` pointing to the next one) and then dereference use `*(input++)` or `*input++`.
- If you mean dereference and increment value pointer points to use `(*input)++`.

Comment: so i need to put (*input)++?

Comment: @LeoS if you meant dereference then increment then yes